# Linq OrderBy specific values not ordering within groupings

Tags: c#, linq

So the title probably makes no sense...

I have a list of products

```
"Ind Apples", "Ind Bananas", "Ind Carrots", "Ind Dates", "Ind Eggplants", "Bulk Apples", "Bulk Bananas", "Bulk Carrots", "Bulk Dates", "Potatoes", "Oranges", "Melons"
```

my linq query is as follows:

```
  var query = db.products
    .OrderBy(c => c.ProductName.StartsWith("Ind"))
    .ThenBy(c => c.ProductName.StartsWith("Bulk"));
```

I want my list to first show all the items that start with "Ind", followed by the items that start with "Bulk", followed by everything else...

What I am getting in my list is the following:

```
"Ind Bananas"
"Ind Eggplants"
"Ind Carrots"
"Ind Apples"
"Bulk Apples"
"Bulk Dates"
"Bulk Carrots"
"Bulk Bananas"
"Oranges"
"Melons"
"Potatoes"
```

so it is ordering by my specification... but within each grouping "Ind", "Bulk" it isn't... Is there a way (other than going through the list and manually specifying where I want each item) to achieve this in linq????

Answer (score 3):

I would chain conditional operators in the outer grouping then just group by the string:

```
var query = db.products
              .OrderBy(c => c.ProductName.StartsWith("Ind") ? 0 : 
                            c.ProductName.StartsWith("Bulk") ? 1 : 2)
              .ThenBy(c => c.ProductName);
```

or

```
var query = db.products
              .OrderBy(c => c.ProductName.StartsWith("Ind") ? 0 : 1)
              .ThenBy(c => c.ProductName.StartsWith("Bulk") ? 0 : 1)
              .ThenBy(c => c.ProductName);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
 OrderByDescending(c => c.FruitType.StartsWith("Ind")).ThenBy(c => c).ThenBy(c => c.FruitType.StartsWith("Bulk"));
```

The .ThenBy(c =>c) in the middle should enforce an alphabetical sort.

Comment: I apologize for posing my answer as a question. I will take note of that.

Comment: Yes.  I also specified .ThenBy(c=>c.ProductName) at the end and that didn't work.

Comment: It is like I need to do an orderby INSIDE each of the orderbys that are already there, but you can't...

Comment: I just tried it with a little different LINQ query, and it ordered it correctly. I edited my answer.